# I've been approved for a quota increase, yet the increase hasn't propagated to Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I went through the approval process of having my Youtube Data API quota (units/day) increased over 2 months ago. Yet, I am not seeing the increase within Google Cloud Platform. Here is a picture of the display in which I am talking about.

[image: Google Cloud Platform Display]

I am wondering if this is a bug within GCP, or potentially my quota was never even increased upon approval?

Comment: It's very unlikely that something is wrong with the developers console. Certainly, for some reason, your quota hasn't been increased yet.

Answer (score 0):

Quota increases as follows :

1. Google verifies your need of quota increase
2. Justification needed for quota increase
3. If Google increases quota, it is not permanent
4. If your usage decreases for a certain period of time then increased quota would revert to default quota

Its like happens the same on my couple of project but didn't found any public document, when I opened ticket with gcp team and they mentioned me the same. To verify your situation open issuetracker case with gcp team

Answer (score 0):

Its like happens the same on my couple of project but didn't found any public document,  when I opened ticket with gcp team and they mentioned me the same

Comment: Thanks for explaining the source for your earlier post.  Instead of providing this second answer, please edit your original answer to include this additional information. The statements make the most sense together.

Comment: Also link back the respective issue tracker page herein, within your post.